# Discord.py "Za Warudo" Bot Command

Tags: discord, discord.py

I'm making a bot command that...

1. Locks the channel; making no one able to send messages.
2. Sends an image and a message.
3. Waits 10 seconds before unlocking the channel, allowing others to send images.

However, I have tried different messages such as changing the role name and different sleep times, and the bot does not send a message, modify commands, or what it was intended to do. It is only this command that doesn't function, and no errors pop up in the console.
Could someone help me, please?

````
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def warudo(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.set_permissions(ctx.verified, send_messages=False)
    await ctx.send('***Za Warudo!***')
    
    await ctx.send(file=discord.File('https://pics.me.me/thumb_you-thought-it-was-an-emoji-but-it-was-me-71487398.png'))
    await ctx.send( ctx.channel.mention + "has paused.")

    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    await ctx.channel.set_permissions(ctx.verified, send_messages=True)```
````

Comment: So what is ctx.verified? I didn't know this exists..

Comment: {ctx.verified} is {ctx.role} . . . maybe that's what's wrong?

Comment: Update: Nope, it wasn't the issue. My intentions by {ctx.verified} was to only restrict the messages sent by those with the role "verified".

Comment: So where have you defined ctx.verified? Because as it is not in the docs, you have to somehow modify the module or define it somewhere

Comment: I've changed it around abit, (for a few days,) and it looks more like ```@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def warudo(ctx):
    verified = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='verified')
    await ctx.channel.set_permissions(ctx.verified, send_messages=False) . . .``` , however, I have a new issue; guild is undefined

Comment: Yes, as you need to use `ctx.guild.roles`. Easy explanation: how would it get the guild out of nowhere? Your bot could be or is in many guilds and would not directly think like 'ah, yes, this one is it'.    And the ctx.verified now works? Have you tested it?

Comment: Ok, stupid question about that with ctx.verified, forget about that, just can't edit it xD